# R 4.1.2: Put DF values in a vector then change their values in a function by referring to their position in the vector

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, function

Trying to create an array/vector of values from a df which I can point to in a function to change those values. Example is a pseudo example as my df is actually larger, but concept is the same.

I'm obviously doing this wrong, but if someone could point out my error(s) it would be appreciated.

```
#Create Df 
df=data.frame(ID=numeric(),
              q1=numeric(),
              q2=numeric())
              
set.seed(1)
for(i in 1:2){
  list_i=c(i)
  df[i,]=list_i
}

#Put df values in a vector???
scores=c(df[1,2],df[2,1])
#Try change score by pointing to its position in vector?
scores[1]=7
#Value remains unchanged in DF
#Create function to replicate the above?
ChangeScores=function(temp){
  scores[1]=temp
}
ChangeScores(99)
#Value remains unchanged in DF as expected as first code did not work
```

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly your goal is?
I don't know why you expect the values to change in df. They change in the vector "scores" which you created. If you want scores to be part of df, you have to add it with the $ operator (df$scores = c(df[1,2], df[2,1]).

Comment: My goal is to use a function to change the scores for brevity. The real data frame I am using has more scores which is being tested against a script to generate an output. The scores need to change for each test, so I wanted to use a function to to do this.

Comment: Your code seems to adds another column, I want to modify the existing values already in the columns.

Comment: Do you want all scores in the question columns (q1, q2 ...) to be changed to new values for the tests ( i.e. all values "1" should be changed to "7" both in q1 and q2) or only the scores on specific positions?

Comment: Hi, what I wanted was a dynamic function to change the values in a df which needs to have its various scores changed as I am transforming it against a scoring script.

For example, in my real DF which has just one row and 40 or so columns, I could change each score by df[1,6]=99 for example. But I wanted to store the rows (lets say just 10 of them) in an array and then use a function to point to the array position which refers to the column in the df and change it that way

instead of coding df[1,6]=99
df[1,2]=999
df[1,9]=9999 etc.